# Multiple inputs for EmrActivity

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, amazon-data-pipeline

According to Data Pipeline documentation the EMRActivity Step command uses a different format than a regular EMR Job.

Here is a simplified example:

```
/home/hadoop/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming.jar,-input,s3://mybucket/folder1/*.gz,-output,s3://output,-mapper=mapper,-reduce=reducer.
```

Let's say I need to pull data from multiple buckets, how can I pass those multiple inputs to a single step command?

In a regular EMR job setup I'd just separate the input paths with commas, but that does not seem to work for the EmrActivity.

I am really interested in a solution for EmrActivity, as opposed to setting up Copy Activities to bring my data to a temporary unique location.

Thanks.

Comment: few of the things I tired: calling -input multiple times, passing an array to -input, using -files. no luck.

Comment: looks like all I had to do was to escape the comma (\,) that separate multiple paths in the -input param value, such as: /home/hadoop/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming.jar,-input,s3://mybucket/folder1/*.gz\,s3://mybucket/folder2/*.gz,-output,s3://output,-mapper=mapper,-reduce=reducer.

Comment: I get "Invalid \escape" when i try to escape the comma..

Answer (score 0):

Using cli escaping is required for validating json. Try "\," if using json from CLI. (\,) will work from console.